# IndexedDB: Can you manually initiate a version change transaction?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, indexeddb

I am writing a Chrome extension that utilizes [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) to store some information client side in an [`IDBObjectStore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore) within an [`IDBDatabase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase).

The nature of the data is such that I need my users to be able to modify the object store at their whim. (add new objects modify existing ones etc.) I am accomplishing this through a settings page and all is fine and dandy so far.

The caveat comes when I want to release a new version of the (default) object store. If I didn't care about overwriting my users' data, then I could just handle the [`onupgradeneeded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBOpenDBRequest/onupgradeneeded) event the same way I handle it when it is fired in reaction to a fresh install. Which would be something like:

```
var request = window.indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, CURRENT_DB_VERSION);
request.onupgradeneeded = upgrade;
function upgrade(event){
  var db = event.target.result;
  var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("domains", {keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true});
  objectStore.createIndex("domain", "domain", {multiEntry: true });
  for(var i=0; i<tags.length; i++){
    objectStore.add(tags[i]);
    console.log("added " + tags[i]["domain"] + " to the IDBObjectStore 'domains' in the IDBDatabase 'Tags' (Format)");
  }
}
```

...but I do care.

So, what I am currently doing is placing a conditional inside of the `upgrade(event)` function that checks for the truthyness of [`event.oldVersion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBVersionChangeEvent) (its 0 on a fresh install). If the value is greater than 0, then I open a new tab that contains an options page where the user can pick and choose which objects he wants to update.

**Now the tricky part:** Once this page closes I need to send a message to the background page that contains the necessary upgrade information. Normally, I would just receive the message in my listener and perform the update, utilizing the provided information. However, [`IDBDatabase.createObjectStore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase/createObjectStore) throws an `InvalidStateError` if:

> The method [is] not called from a versionchange transaction callback.

When I look at the spec for [`IDBDatabase.transaction(storenames, mode)`](http://IDBDatabase.transaction()), in the `mode` parameter description, it says:

> `versionchange` mode can't be specified here.

So, it seems to me like I need to trigger an `onupgradeneeded` event, but I also need to pass the event handler an additional parameter, besides the event itself, which contains information that it can use to decide how to perform the upgrade.

I don't know how to go about doing this though.

Can anyone offer me some insight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting `InvalidStateError` because you may not be calling `IDBDatabase.createObjectStore()` from `onupgradeneeded` event handler. In case of IDB, all object store creation and manipulation has to happen from inside of `onupgradeneeded` event handler or after `onupgradeneeded` is triggered.

If I understood your requirement correctly then you do not want to override the user's existing object store in certain conditions, and for that you want to pass some information in `onupgradeneeded` event handler to tell whether to create afresh object store or do some modification on top of existing object store.

My recommendation would be - have 2 global array variables `DB_SCHEMA_DROP_QUERIES` and `DB_SCHEMA_CREATE_QUERIES` which you can prepare with drop and create data before opening the database using `window.indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, CURRENT_DB_VERSION);`

Then have code as below (I am just giving a heads up), so when you want to **1.**    create afresh database then first drop all your existing data stores from database and create new (which means populate both `DB_SCHEMA_DROP_QUERIES` and `DB_SCHEMA_CREATE_QUERIES`). **2.** just add one more object store then only prepare `DB_SCHEMA_CREATE_QUERIES` **3.** modify an existing object store then prepare both `DB_SCHEMA_DROP_QUERIES` and `DB_SCHEMA_CREATE_QUERIES` but only for that particular object store

Basically what we are trying to achieve to making the things dynamic instead of hard-coding data store creation like this `db.createObjectStore("domains", {keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true});`. This will also help you to get rid of maintaining version records.

```
var dropQueriesLength = DB_SCHEMA_DROP_QUERIES.length;
for(var i =0; i < dropQueriesLength; i++){
try{
    DB_HANDLER.deleteObjectStore(DB_SCHEMA_DROP_QUERIES[i].name);
} catch(e){

}
}

for(var i =0; i < DB_SCHEMA_CREATE_QUERIES.length; i++){
  var objectStore = null;
    if(DB_SCHEMA_CREATE_QUERIES[i].primaryKeyCol != null && DB_SCHEMA_CREATE_QUERIES[i].primaryKeyCol != undefined){
        objectStore = DB_HANDLER.createObjectStore(DB_SCHEMA_CREATE_QUERIES[i].name, { keyPath: DB_SCHEMA_CREATE_QUERIES[i].primaryKeyCol});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The only way to trigger an upgrade-style transaction (a version change transaction) is to open a connection with a larger version number.